# Python3 having problems passing *args and **kwargs to a threading.Timer() and a function

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, timer, args, keyword-argument

for some reason I am having trouble passing *args and **kwargs to both a threading.Timer() and a function...here is the code I am having trouble with;

```
from threading import Timer

def print_me(text='foo'):
    print(text)

def repeat_task(delay, action, *args, **kwargs):
    Timer(delay, repeat_task, (delay, action, [*args], {**kwargs}).start()
    action(*args, **kwargs)

repeat_task( 5, print_me, text='bar' )
```

if anyone could point me in the right direction I would be very appreciative. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[*args]` and `{**kwargs}` are both invalid syntax. `kwargs` is already a `dict`, so if you want it as a dict, just use it directly. `args` is a `tuple`, so if you want its value as a tuple, just use it directly, and if you want to turn it into a `list` for some reason, you can use `list(args)`.

You're passing these arguments to `Timer()`, [whose parameters are defined as](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Timer):

```
Timer(interval, function, args=None, kwargs=None)
```

Notice that there are no `*`s there: the `args` and `kwargs` parameters for this constructor are *normal* parameters.

So your third argument needs to be all your positional arguments: `delay` and `action`, then all the contents of `args`. One way to do this is to add lists together with `+`:

```
[delay, action] + list(args)
```

And your fourth argument needs to be the keyword arguments, which is just `kwargs`.

So this should work:

```
Timer(delay, repeat_task, [delay, action] + list(args), kwargs).start()
```

Comment: aaah you are right, however it isn't that line spitting out the error...it is this one "action(args, kwargs)" (I probably should have clarified that in my question) the error says "TypeError: unorderable types: dict() >= int()"

Comment: eer acutally that is a new error...your comment actually fixed it. :) now I need to figure out this new error...lol